# Get random selection from list in immutablejs

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Underscore js has a sample function which will "Produce a random sample from the list. Pass a number to return n random elements from the list. Otherwise a single random item will be returned."

I have an immutable list but I see no clear way to do get 10 random items from the list. How can this be accomplished in immutablejs?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much just taking the [annotated source from underscore.js for sample](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-40) - and rewriting for an Immutable list. There are better ways to do this, this is mainly just a demonstration of - when in doubt, take the function you want and rewrite it to suit your needs. Optimize from there:

```
_immu = {};
_immu.sample = function(list, n) {
  if (n === undefined) return list.get(_immu.random(list.size - 1));
  return _immu.shuffle(list).slice(0, Math.max(0, n));
};

_immu.shuffle = function(list) {
  var set = list;
  var size = set.size;
  var shuffled = Immutable.List(Array(size));
  for (var index = 0, rand; index < size; index++) {
    rand = _immu.random(0, index);
    if (rand !== index) shuffled = shuffled.set(index, shuffled.get(rand));
    shuffled = shuffled.set(rand, set.get(index));
  }
  return shuffled;
};

_immu.random = function(min, max) {
  if (max == null) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
};
```

Works the same way as sample so can be invoked by:

```
var list = Immutable.List([1,2,3,4,5])
_immu.sample(list, 3).toJS() //toJS here is just to show it as an array
```

Edited to add JSBin: https://jsbin.com/levigemina/edit?js,console,output